# VBA Macro Excel if statement issue

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to send a bulk of emails based on a certain condition. The If statement is not working not sure why, the emails get generated but completely ignores the if statement. The value in the columns are in percentage format

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'New Variables to define'
Dim EmailTo As String
Dim EmailAddress As String
Dim Value As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim RowCounter As Integer
Dim ValueAxes As Double
Dim eMsg As String
Dim eSig As String
Dim InpSht As Worksheet

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set InpSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Axes")

'Allocated and created'
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'For loop'
LastRow = InpSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For RowCounter = 2 To LastRow
EmailTo = InpSht.Range("A" & RowCounter).Value
EmailAddress = InpSht.Range("C" & RowCounter).Value
ValueAxes = InpSht.Range("B" & RowCounter).Value
    
    If InpSht.Range("B" & RowCounter).Value > -50 Then
     With OutMail
    .To = EmailAddress
    .Cc = ""
    .Subject = "Example & ValueAxes
    .HTMLbody = EmailTo & eMsg & eSig
    .display
    
    End With
    End If
Next RowCounter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `Debug.Print InpSht.Range("B" & RowCounter).Value, VarType(InpSht.Range("B" & RowCounter).Value)` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: If it is a percent you probably want -.5? unless you're actually looking for -5000%

Comment: @BigBen it returns 0

Comment: @Warcupine I tried -.5 but it still ignores the if statement and sends emails to all the list even if they have more than -50%

Comment: That should return more than just `0`... it should return both the cell's value and its `VarType`. What does it return for one iteration of the loop, i.e. using `For RowCounter = 2 To 3`?

Comment: @BigBen It now prints the percent as a double and 5 as a VarType for all of them

Comment: By the way, you realize you've only created *one* email right? If you want multiple emails, you need to move `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)` inside the loop.

Comment: @BigBen Nvm i get what you said, i fixed that, but how can i fix the if statement issue?

Comment: Do you have your comparison sign flipped? As you have it now with `>-50` it will pick up everything from -4999.99% to 5000% and beyond.